# Calculating an integral with a matrix

Tags: integration, matrices

I want to calculate the following integral:

Let A be a symmetric, invertible matrix.

$\int_{K}<A^2x,x>dx$ where $K:=\{x\in \mathbb R^n : \|Ax\|_2\leq1\}$

A is symmetric, hence there is an invertible matrix U, such that $U^{T}AU=D$ with a diagonal matrix.

Then we have (Substitution: x=Uy):

$\int_{K}<A^2x,x>dx$=$\int_{K}x^{T}A^{T}A^{T}xdx$=$\int_{K'}y^{T}U^{T}A^{T}A^{T}Uydy$=$\int_{K'}y^{T}U^{T}A^{T}UU^{T}A^{T}Uydy$=$\int_{K'}y^{T}D^2ydy$=$\int_{K'}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2\lambda_i dy$

With $K':=\{y\in \mathbb R^n:\|AUy\|_2\leq1 \}$

But how to continue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong transformation. Why not use $y=Ax$? In this case, you are looking at:
$$
\int_{K'}\|y\|^2d(A^{-1}y)=|A|^{-1}\int_{K'}\|y\|^2dy, K'=\{y\in\mathbb R^n:\|y\|\leq 1\}
$$
Basically, you want to compute the integration on a $(n-1)$-ball. So...spherical coordinates will be a perfect choice right? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element), we have:
$$
dy=dy_1\cdots dy_n=r^{n-1}drd\cdots
$$
So:
$$
|A|^{-1}\int_{K'}\|y\|^2dy=|A|^{-1}\int_{K'}r^2r^{n-1}drd\cdots
$$
If you consider the difference of $\int_0^1r^{n-1}dr$ with $\int_0^1r^{n+1}dr$, you realize that:
$$
\int_0^1r^{n+1}dr=\frac{n}{n+2}\int_0^1r^{n-1}dr
$$ 
So:
$$
|A|^{-1}\int_{K'}r^2r^{n-1}drd\cdots=|A|^{-1}\frac{n}{n+2}V_{n-1}
$$
where $V_{n-1}$ is the volume of a $(n-1)$-ball with radius $1$. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area):
$$
V_{n-1}=\frac{\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}
$$
I know its ugly but at least you have your answer.